# Android: setOnClickListener not working for GridView

Tags: android, gridview

Hi I'm implementing setOnClickListener for GridView parent

**Code:**

**Main layout**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_ll_friends"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:background="@drawable/linear_layout_border"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_img_friends"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_img_apf_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_img_apf_height"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cont_desc"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_480_800"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/friends_photos_gv"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_img_apf_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_img_apf_height" >
            </GridView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_tv_friends"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_img_apf_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/txt_size_height_profile"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@color/txt_common_white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/txt_Friends"
                android:textColor="@color/txt_common_black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
LinearLayout friendsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.profile_ll_friends);

friendsLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, FriendsListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**Adapter Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/friends_photos_img"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cont_desc"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_480_800"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When clicking on TextView (profile_tv_friends) area, setOnClickListener working fine but when clicking on GridView (friends_photos_gv) area, setOnClickListener is not working

For this problem i tried

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

for ImageView (friends_photos_img) in the adapter layout and also tried

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

for LinearLayout (profile_ll_friends), but setOnClickListener is not working when clicking on GridView area

Comment: you haven't added click listener that's why it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
friendlayout.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {

        // DO something

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A Gridview works like a listview you can try something like this.

```
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {

        // DO something

    }
    });
```

For more information checkout this link. [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html)

Another mistake might be that you are referencing the linearlayout here instead of your actual GridView.

```
LinearLayout friendsLayout = (LinearLayout)   findViewById(R.id.profile_ll_friends);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
friendsLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

with:

```
friendsLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```